# Looking to retrieve specific record

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have multilple records by employee, location, and last updated, and I need to pick only the one with Max(LastUpdated) for each employee.

```
employee    location    lastupdated
59  All locations   2017-10-23T15:44:53
12  Payroll and Benefits    2017-10-23T06:26:44
13  North York  2017-10-26T09:41:52
13  East York   2017-10-06T12:05:40
13  North York  2017-10-18T14:25:36
14  CEO     2017-10-26T09:45:58
14  DownTown    2017-08-01T16:44:54
15  Energey 2017-10-24T08:22:35
15  Smart Buildings 2017-10-25T19:59:53
```

For example, the following records should be returned:

```
    59  All locations   2017-10-23T15:44:53
    12  Payroll and Benefits    2017-10-23 T06:26:44
    13  North York  2017-10-26T09:41:52
    14  CEO 2017-10-26T09:45:58
    15  Smart Buildings 2017-10-25T19:59:53


SELECT employee, location, max(lastupdated)
FROM employee
GROUP BY employee, location;
```

This is not working as max date is selected based on employee and location, I want to select just one record, with max(lastupdated), that record should contain employee, location, and lastupdated fields.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few solutions:

```
SELECT TOP 1 employee, location, lastupdated
FROM employee
ORDER BY lastupdated DESC
```

This will always return 1 record, and if there are ties it will just pick one.  This may or may not be what you want.  If you want ties, you can specify `SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES [...]`.

Alternately:

```
SELECT employee, location, lastupdated
FROM employee
WHERE lastupdated = (SELECT MAX(lastupdated) FROM employee)
```

Here you will always get all ties, so you may get multiple records in case of a tie.  Again, this may or may not be what you want.

---

Given your updated question:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT employee,
        location,
        lastupdated, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY lastupdated DESC) rn
    FROM employee
)
SELECT employee, location, lastupdated
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This is the "greatest N per group" problem.  This is the typical solution (everywhere except MySQL).  If you want to include ties, then you should use the `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` analytic function instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. This question is answered.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad. As per my other message, [please read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Accepting answers is not mandatory here, but it is a bit like saying "thank you" - it gives the helpful person a few internet points for the assistance they have rendered.